# How to parse new data in dynamic TableLayout on scrolling to the bottom?

Tags: android, dynamic, tablelayout

I have created a dynamic TableLayout. In rows of table I show data parsed from server.In once data comes only for 20 rows (by using pageno=1 in url of server).On increasing pageno value it gives next 20 row's data.
And what I want is that when I scroll to the last row of table so the next data should be parsed and new rows should be appended to table.

any suggestions...

Please Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution my own.

I put TableLayout in a ScrollView and caluclated the y position of the 20th element when I scroll it up.So whenever I scroll just before the calculated y position I parse new data with (say pageno = 2) and create new row and add to TableLayout.
And also increase the value of y to y+y.

Idea for calculating y of scrolled position from [here](http://arunbadole1209.wordpress.com/2011/10/03/how-to-make-simultaneous-scrollable-views-in-android/) .